# Можно ли установить Ratchet (websockets) на denwer, а не на XAMPP?

Tags: php, websocket, denwer, xampp, ratchet

Хочу сделать real-time app в виде чата из под windows. PhpDaemon отпадает, так как нужна виртуалка с linux; NodeJs + socket.io это хорошо, но хотелось бы php. Выбор пал на Ratchet. Смотрю на установку - "you need a web server such as WAMP or XAMPP", но у меня уже есть denwer и плодить их не хочется.

Собственно вопрос, могу ли использовать denwer вместо XAMPP, чтобы всё работало, или же denwer не является веб-сервером, тогда почему он им не является, ведь компоненты одни и те же (apache + php + mysql..)

Comment: XAMPP тоже не является вебсервером. Как и WAMP. Вебсервером в этих двоих является Apache.

Comment: Странно, по этой ссылке я обучаюсь http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/websocket-server-php , и там именно фраза "web server such as WAMP or XAMPP". По вашему раз получается apache - server, тогда можно и ограничиться denwer без установки всяких xampp wamp?

Comment: Вполне может быть. Попробуйте.